# What is the difference for each case of this sealed class?

Tags: kotlin

While looking at the sample code to use the `sealed class`, I saw several cases in which the method of using the `sealed class` was different.

`case1` is similar to `enum class`, but I know that it can create multiple `instances`.

But what makes `case2` different?
And I'm wondering what's the difference between inheriting from a `normal class(or interface)`

### case1

> The first case is the most common sealed class method in the sample code.

```
sealed class Parent(
    val t1: String,
    val t2: String,
) {
    data class A(
        val id: String,
        val title: String,
        val num : Int
    ) : Parent(
        t1 = id,
        t2 = title,
    ) { }
    
    data class B(
        val id: String,
        val title: String,
    ) : Parent(
        t1 = id,
        t2 = title,
    ) { }
}
```

### case2

> The second case is a case where you are curious about the difference from inheriting a normal class.

```
sealed class Parent(
    val t1: String,
    open val t2: String,
) { }
data class A(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val num : Int
) : Parent(
    t1 = id,
    t2 = title,
) { }

data class B(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
) : Parent(
    t1 = id,
    t2 = title,
) { }
```

```
open class Parent( // or interface
    val t1: String,
    open val t2: String,
) { }
data class A(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val num : Int
) : Parent(
    t1 = id,
    t2 = title,
) { }

data class B(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
) : Parent(
    t1 = id,
    t2 = title,
) { }
```

Comment: The only difference I can spot is where they are defined, inside or outside the parent class body. In Case 1 you would have to either type out `Parent.A` when using the child class instead of just `A` or else import the child class specifically. It’s just a code organization technique. The two cases behave the same.

Comment: When creating class `A`, `case1` is created in the `val a = Parent.A()` method and `case2` is created in this way `val a = A()`, right? If so, is it just a difference in the creation method?

Comment: It's more a difference in how the class is named. In the first example, because all the members of the sealed class are nested inside it, they're all referenced as `Parent.Member` - there's a relationship between the sealed class and the members of that class that's expressed in the name itself. Might help to think of a concrete example, like `RequestStatus.Pending`, `RequestStatus.Success`, ``RequestStatus.Failed`` and so on - you don't have a `Success` class floating around, you have to specify it as a member of `RequestStatus`. You can nest multiple sealed classes to create a hierarchy too

Comment: @cactustictacs 
thanks. By the way, I understand roughly, but let me ask you a few more questions.
`Q1`. You said it had to do with the `class name`, isn't that also true for `case2`? Are `case2` and `case1` just a difference in reference method like `Parent.Member` after all?

`Q2`. I don't understand what `Success class floating around means`...

Comment: Nesting classes inside other classes is a way to create namespaces in Java (and Kotlin) - it's a way of organising things, grouping things together, and keeping stuff that relates to a specific class "attached" to it. Like, what is a ``Success``? If it's at the top level, you have some class called ``Success`` that will show up in autocomplete, and you might not know what it even relates to without digging into it. Whereas if you have to access it as ``RequestStatus.Success``, it's much clearer what it is, what it relates to, and where you might find any other possible statuses

Comment: Another reason to nest a class definition inside another class (other than changing the way it is named) is so it can see protected and private members of that class when working with instances of that outer class. This is rarely necessary though.

Comment: @cactustictacs 
If so, is it a difference in expression? `case1` is more intuitive and clearer and can indicate a relationship with a subclass.
After all, is `case2` only different from `case1` in the way it is represented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1:**

- uses nested classes.
- was the required way to do sealed classes in Kotlin before 1.5.
- suggests a direct relationship between the nessted and outer class that you might want to carry throughout your code for clarity (like `PaymentType.CreditCard`, `PaymentType.Checking`, etc), so can be used as a grouping / organizing strategy
- requires scoping when declaring fields (`val paymentMethod = PaymentMethod.CreditCard(...)`) or adding extra imports

**Case 2:**

- no more nested classes
- only possible as of Kotlin 1.5
- suggests a less direct relationship between the base and derived classes that doesn't require being maintained throughout the code (like `Animal`, `Cat`, `Dog`, etc)
- Does not require scoping or extra imports (`val cat = Cat()`)

Finally:

> And I'm wondering what's the difference between inheriting from a normal class(or interface)

The Kotlin docs are pretty clear on [sealed classes](http://And%20I%27m%20wondering%20what%27s%20the%20difference%20between%20inheriting%20from%20a%20normal%20class(or%20interface)) and [regular classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html). The key point for sealed classes being:

> Sealed classes and interfaces represent restricted class hierarchies that provide more control over inheritance. All direct subclasses of a sealed class are known at compile time. No other subclasses may appear after a module with the sealed class is compiled. For example, third-party clients can't extend your sealed class in their code. Thus, each instance of a sealed class has a type from a limited set that is known when this class is compiled.

In short: they're `enums` on crack. (PSA: don't do crack).

Comment: Good call. Updated.

Comment: In summary, `case1` is more clear and intuitive, and the relationship between sealed and nested classes is more direct than `case2`. Instance declarations also differ in scope specification. There is a slight difference between the two, but it is the same thing only with a difference in the way of expression. Is that right? And I still don't quite understand the difference between sealed class and regular class inheritance. It's difficult. I'm sorry.